# external Internet Explorer css problems

Tags: css

I created and linked an external CSS for all versions of IE after building my website for Safari and Firefox. However, once I linked this extra style sheet, several things happened:

1. My background image on only the index page failed to show up in Safari.
2. The webpage is no longer centered.
3. When I linked the IE style sheet, the .js files went away in the file menu bar (across the top where it shows each of the files linked to the source code) in Dreamweaver (but still worked live)

When I unlinked the IE style sheet, the index page's `bg` image returned in Safari, but my content is still not centered. You can [see my website here](http://www.sarawalkercreative.com). As you will see, I'm a beginner and have many issues to sort out yet.

Any idea why linking this style sheet caused so many problems?

Greatly appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Is the IE style sheet linked or not linked on your live site?

Comment: I just removed the link - just now.

Comment: You can use [conditional comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx) to make the CSS targets IE only.

Comment: you are using jquery and which version? can you see any javascript error in IE?

Comment: No error in IE for the javascript - that works fine. The index page has jquery blades. The Web, Graphics and Illustration has the latest version of lightbox by Lokesh Dhakar

Answer (score 0):

```
Add Doctype like this will solve multiple IE issues
<!--[if IE]>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<![endif]-->
```